# Making a Racket function that applies to lists

Tags: lisp, racket, paradigms

How to apply a function to a list in the racket?

Comment: See apply: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html

Answer (score 1):

[This answer belonged to [v1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67880957/1) of the question which was quite different: it makes limited sense now.]

To transform a list in this way using a function `f`

- map a function over the list which

  - if the element is a list, transforms it with the function `f`
  - otherwise calls `f` on the element.